# How to update mass record by user_id?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Laravel how to update all records by user_id. I want to update all records by user_id in that form. And there is error like

> Missing required parameters for [Route: choices.update]

**my database**

```
|----|---------|-------|-----------------|----------|
| id | user_id |  time | question_number | topic_id |
|----|---------|-------|-----------------|----------|
| 1  |    1    | 60:00 |        10       |    1     |
|----|---------|-------|-----------------|----------|
| 2  |    1    | 60:00 |        5        |    2     |
|----|---------|-------|-----------------|----------|
.....................................................
| 10 |    2    | 30:00 |        5        |    1     |
|----|---------|-------|-----------------|----------|
| 11 |    2    | 30:00 |        7        |    2     |
|----|---------|-------|-----------------|----------|
```

**trying update like this**

```
|----|---------|-------|-----------------|----------|
| id | user_id |  time | question_number | topic_id |
|----|---------|--------|-----------------|----------|
| 1  |    1    | 120:00 |        25       |    1     |
|----|---------|--------|-----------------|----------|
| 2  |    1    | 120:00 |        4        |    2     |
|----|---------|--------|-----------------|----------|
......................................................
| 10 |    2    | 90:00  |       15        |    1     |
|----|---------|--------|-----------------|----------|
| 11 |    2    | 90:00  |       19        |    2     |
|----|---------|----=---|-----------------|----------|
```

**View**

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('choices.update') }}">
{{ csrf_field() }}
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr class="info">
        <th>№</th>
        <th>Нэр</th>
        <th>Сэдэв</th>
        <th>Асуултын тоо</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach($choices as $choice)
        <tr>
        <td>{{ $choice->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ Auth::user()->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $choice->topic->title }}</td>
        <td><input value="{{ $choice->question_number }}"
                   name="number[{{ $choice->id }}]" step="1" min="0"></td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
        </tbody>
        </table>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Хадгалах</a>
</form>
```

**Route**

```
   |        | GET|HEAD  | choices                                   | choices.index                  | App\Http\Controllers\ChoicesController@index                           | web,auth                                     |
   |        | POST      | choices                                   | choices.store                  | App\Http\Controllers\ChoicesController@store                           | web,auth                                     |
   |        | GET|HEAD  | choices/create                            | choices.create                 | App\Http\Controllers\ChoicesController@create                          | web,auth                                     |
   |        | DELETE    | choices/{choice}                          | choices.destroy                | App\Http\Controllers\ChoicesController@destroy                         | web,auth                                     |
   |        | PUT|PATCH | choices/{choice}                          | choices.update                 | App\Http\Controllers\ChoicesController@update                          | web,auth                                     |
   |        | GET|HEAD  | choices/{choice}                          | choices.show                   | App\Http\Controllers\ChoicesController@show                            | web,auth                                     |
   |        | GET|HEAD  | choices/{choice}/edit                     | choices.edit                   | App\Http\Controllers\ChoicesController@edit                             | web,auth                                     |
```

**Controller**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id){
    foreach ($request->input('number') as $key => $value) {
        Choice::where('user_id',Auth::id())->update([
            'user_id' => Auth::id(),
            'time'  => $time,
            'topic_id' => $key,
            'question_number' => $value,
        ]);
    }
}
```

then i gotta write something to provide my code. but I don't know how.

Comment: in form action add user_id action="{{ route('choices.update', $user_id) }}"

Comment: post your route

Comment: I added my route list on Question please check @RahulShrivastava

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far i.e. your controller code for that route?

Comment: your controller param should be like this :public function update(Request $request, $id) and from code : <form method="post" action="{{ route('choices.update',$choice->id) }}">

Answer (score 0):

Add the `$choice->id` to the route :

```
{{ route('choices.update', $choice->id) }}
```

This should get rid of the `Missing required parameters`.

As for doing the "mass update", I would suggest creating a new route as the current route should be used for updating a single `choice` e.g.

```
Route::put('user/choices', ...) //Obviously, you change "put" to be post or patch if you want.
```

Laravel doesn't currently (as far as I know) support `ON DUPLICATE KEY`, however, you could use a package like [this](https://packagist.org/packages/yadakhov/insert-on-duplicate-key).

Also, in your form your setting the key for `number` with the choice id but then in your controller you're using the key for the topic id which I not sure is right.

Comment: Wait a minute . But is it can do mass update records?

Comment: I added my controller@update . please check this out